# Positioning elements Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the codepen below, I'm trying to make it look like the attached image at all sizes. Two things are not working correctly - in the first line with numbers, the green numbers are the day's price change and change percent (the only green text on the page). At the large browser size they are drifting apart too much. Is there a way to force them to stay next to each other in all sizes?

I'm also having difficulty figuring out how to make the inline-form text input field always take up 50% of that line, and make the 'Get new Quote' button always take up 50% at all sizes - like in the attached image.

[image: Image of how it should look at all sizes]
[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/michael-kaufman/pen/WvjvRg/)

```
<head>
  <title>Stock Quotes</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <meta name='viewport' content='"width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div id='quote-module' class='col-md-12'>
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-*'>
      <hr id='hruleFat' />
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-12 pull-left' id='companyName'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='prices' class='row'>
      <div id='lastPrice' class='col-md-8 pull-left'></div>
      <div id='changes'>
        <div id='changePercent' class='col-md-2 pull-right'></div>
        <div id='change' class='col-md-2 pull-right'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id='range'>
      <p class='pull-right'></p>Range</div>
    <hr>
    <div id='open'>
      <p class='pull-right'></p>Open</div>
    <hr>
    <div id='volume'>
      <p class='pull-right'></p>Volume</div>
    <hr>
    <div id='marketCap'>
      <p class='pull-right'></p>Market Cap</div>
    <hr>
    <div class='row'>
      <div id='time' class='col-md-* pull-right'></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id='getQuoteForm'>
      <form class='form-inline col-md-*' id='getQuote'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type='text' class='form-control' id='symbolInput'>
        </div>
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default col-md-* '>Get New Quote</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
  <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just remove the class col-md-2 from changePercent and change div's. check this http://jsfiddle.net/8uwbwapp/

Comment: Oh - that works great. I was under the impression things always need to add up to 12.  How about the input field and button part of my question. Would you be able to help with that? Thanks so much!

Comment: oh I didn't see the second half of the question. let me see what I can do with that.

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/8uwbwapp/1/?

Comment: I can't thank you enough - obviously I'm over thinking how Bootstrap works.

Comment: glad it works for u. if it helped u I can post the solution as an answer. please mark it as an answer

Comment: I clicked the up arrows, but how do I mark it as an answer?

Comment: One last question - any idea why it doesn't work in Full Screen share mode? I don't think it did on codePen or Plunker either. Is that because of cross-domain policies getting the data?

Comment: let me post it as an answer below and then you can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the class `col-md-2` from `changePercent` and `change` div's. 
here's the jsfiddle for this [jsfiddle.net/8uwbwapp/1](http://jsfiddle.net/8uwbwapp/1)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your both changes. Please see below changes I have made in codepen:

```js
function fireAjax(url) {

  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      $('h1').html(data.Name);
      $('.container #companyName').html(data.Name);
      $('#lastPrice').html(data.LastPrice.toFixed(2));
      $('#change').html(data.Change.toFixed(2));
      $('#changePercent').html("(" + data.ChangePercent.toFixed(2) + "%)");
      $('#range p').html(data.Low + '-' + data.High);
      $('#open p').html(data.Open.toFixed(2));
      $('#volume p').html(Math.round(data.Volume / 100000));
      $('#marketCap p').html(Math.round(data.MarketCap / 1000000000));

      var vol = data.Volume.toString();
      if (vol > 6) {
        $('#volume p').append('M');
      }

      var cap = data.Volume.toString();
      if (cap > 7) {
        $('#marketCap p').append('B')
      }

      var date = new Date();
      var hours = date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours();
      var am_pm = date.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
      var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
      var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
      time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + am_pm;
      $('#time').html('As of ' + time);

    }
  })
}

fireAjax('http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL')

$("#getQuote").submit(function(event) {
  var newURL = 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=' + $('#symbolInput').val();
  console.log(newURL);
  fireAjax(newURL);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#quote-module {
  border:1px dotted #888;
  background:#EEE;
  min-height:200px;
}

#hruleFat {
  top:10px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 5px;
}

#prices {
  padding-top:25px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
  font-size:18px;
}

#change {
  color: green;
}
#changePercent{
  color: green;
}

#range {
  color: #999;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#open {
  color: #999;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#volume {
  color: #999;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#marketCap {
  color:#999;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#range p{
  color: black;
}
#open p {
  color: black;
}

#volume p {
  color: black;
}


#marketCap p{
  color: black;
}

#time {
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#999;
}


#companyName {
  max-width:20px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:#666;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div id='quote-module' class='col-md-12'>
             <h1></h1>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-*'>
        <hr id='hruleFat' />
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12 pull-left' id='companyName'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='prices' class='row'>
        <div id='lastPrice' class='col-xs-8'></div>
        <div id='changes' class="col-xs-4">
            <div id='changePercent' class=' pull-right'></div>
            <div id='change' class='pull-right'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id='range'>
        <p class='pull-right'></p>Range</div>
    <hr>
    <div id='open'>
        <p class='pull-right'></p>Open</div>
    <hr>
    <div id='volume'>
        <p class='pull-right'></p>Volume</div>
    <hr>
    <div id='marketCap'>
        <p class='pull-right'></p>Market Cap</div>
    <hr>
    <div class='row'>
        <div id='time' class='col-md-* pull-right'></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id='getQuoteForm'>
        <form class='form-inline col-md-*' id='getQuote'>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='symbolInput' style="width:100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default col-xs-12'>Get New Quote</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
    <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
</div>
```